# Ember Data express Node REST back-end

Tags: json, node.js, ember.js, express, ember-data

I have REST backend in node and express environment. My service is generating following JSON

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "Action" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Drama" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "Comedy" },
  { "id": 4, "name": "Romance" }
]
```

Where ember-data requires JSON in following format

```
{
 "genres": [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Action" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Drama" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "Comedy" },
  { "id": 4, "name": "Romance" }
  ]
 }
```

Following is backed code which is generating JSON

```
all : function(req, res){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    if(connection){
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM generes', 
            function(err, rows, fields){
                if(err) throw err;
                res.contentType('application/json');
                res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
                res.end();
            });
    }
}
```

How can I add the resource name in JSON string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({'genres': rows})
```